# GravityForms with GravityWiz Populate Anything DropDown Calculation

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a form with a dropdown that pulls values from another form via Populate Anything.
I want to add up all the values and output them in one field. Not only the selected option but all available

The dropdown field looks like this, for example:
4 participants
3 participants
5 participants

The other form is a registration form for participants. A user can fill this out multiple times

Desired result:
All participants: 12